# Separating two superimposed normal distributions in R

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I am searching for a function/package-name in R which allows one to separate two superimposed normal distributions. The distribution looks something like this:

```
x<-c(3.95, 3.99, 4.0, 4.04, 4.1, 10.9, 11.5, 11.9, 11.7, 12.3)
```

Comment: Why has this been closed as off-topic?

Comment: Given the good answers I'm adding my vote to reopen, but I stand by my original vote.  There's not enough detail about what method they want to implement to make this a mere programming question, and it's too low-quality to migrate to CV.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman: ... and given current CV policies this question would have been considered too programming related for CV.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had good results in the past using vector generalized linear models. The [VGAM package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html) is useful for that.

The `mix2normal1` function allows to estimate the parameters of a mix of two univariate normal distributions.

Little example

```
require(VGAM)
set.seed(12345)

# Create a binormal distribution with means 10 and 20
data <- c(rnorm(100, 10, 1.5), rnorm(200, 20, 3))

# Initial parameters for minimization algorithm
# You may want to create some logic to estimate this a priori... not always easy but possible
# m, m2: Means - s, s2: SDs - w: relative weight of the first distribution (the second is 1-w)
init.params <- list(m=5, m2=8, s=1, s2=1, w=0.5)

fit <<- vglm(data ~ 1, mix2normal1(equalsd=FALSE), 
                iphi=init.params$w, imu=init.params$m, imu2=init.params$m2, 
                isd1=init.params$s, isd2=init.params$s2)

# Calculated parameters
pars = as.vector(coef(fit))
w = logit(pars[1], inverse=TRUE)
m1 = pars[2]
sd1 = exp(pars[3])
m2 = pars[4]
sd2 = exp(pars[5])

# Plot an histogram of the data
hist(data, 30, col="black", freq=F)
# Superimpose the fitted distribution
x <- seq(0, 30, 0.1)
points(x, w*dnorm(x, m1, sd1)+(1-w)*dnorm(x,m2,sd2), "l", col="red", lwd=2)
```

This correctly gives ("true" parameters - 10, 20, 1.5, 3)

```
> m1
[1] 10.49236
> m2
[1] 20.06296
> sd1
[1] 1.792519
> sd2
[1] 2.877999
```

[image: Fit bimodal distribution]

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `nls` , the nonlinear regression tool (or other nonlin regressors).  I'm guessing you have a vector of data representing the superimposed distributions.  Then, roughly,  `nls(y~I(a*exp(-(x-meana)^2/siga) + b*exp(-(x-meanb)^2/sigb) ),{initial guess values required for all constants} )` , where `y` is your distribution and `x` is the domain .
I'm not thinking about this at all, so I'm not sure which convergence methods are less likely to fail.